# JavaScript - Multiplying Even Indexed Array Elements by 2 and Odd Indexed by 3

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to write code that multiplies even indexed elements of an array by 2 and odd indexed elements by 3.

I have the following numbers stored in the variable number, which represents an array of numbers

```
numbers = [1,7,9,21,32,77];
Even Indexed Numbers - 1,9,32
Odd Indexed Numbers - 7, 21, 77
```

Please keep in mind that arrays are Zero Indexed, which means the numbering starts at 0. In which case, the 0-Indexed element is actually 1, and the 1-Indexed element is 7.

This is what I expected the output to be

```
[2,21,18,63,64,231]
```

Unfortunately, I got this output

```
[2,14,17,42,64,154]
```

Here is the code for my method

```
numbers = numbers.map(function(x) {
  n = 0;
  while (n < numbers.length) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
      return x * 2;
    }
    else {
     return x * 3;
    }
    n++;
  }});
return numbers;
```

Here I created a while loop, that executes code for every iteration of the variable n. For every value of the variable n, I'm checking if n is even, which is used by the code n % 2 == 0. While it's true that 0 % 2 == 0 it's not true that 1 % 2 == 0. I'm incrementing n at the end of the while loop, so I don't understand why I received the output I did.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You created a global property called `n`, by doing

```
n = 0;
```

and then,

```
while (n < numbers.length) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return x * 2;
    } else {
        return x * 3;
    }
}
n++;    // Unreachable
```

you always return immediately. So the, `n++` is never incremented. So, `n` remains 0 always and so all the elements are multiplied by `2` always.

The [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)'s callback function's, second parameter is the index itself. So, the correct way to use `map` is, like this

```
numbers.map(function(currentNumber, index) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        return currentNumber * 2;
    } else {
        return currentNumber * 3;
    }
});
```

The same can be written succinctly, with the ternary operator, like this

```
numbers.map(function(currentNumber, index) {
    return currentNumber * (index % 2 === 0 ? 2 : 3);
});
```

Comment: You don't even need an `if` statement or ternary operator. Because `index % 2` has a value of 0 or 1, simply use this in your `map` callback: `return currentNumber * ( 2 + index % 2 );`

Answer (score 3):

To complement the other answer, the source of OP's confusion is on how "map" works. The `map` function is **already** called for each element - yet, OP attempted to use a `while` loop inside it, which is another way to iterate through each element. That is a double interaction, so, in essence, if OP's code worked, it would still be modifying each number `n` times! Usually, you just chose between a loop or map:

Using a loop:

```
var numbers = [1,7,9,21,32,77];
for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; ++i)
    numbers[i] = i % 2 === 0 ? numbers[i] * 2 : numbers[i] * 3;
```

Using map:

```
var numbers = [1,7,9,21,32,77];
numbers.map(function(number, index){
    return number * (index % 2 === 0 ? 2 : 3);
});
```

Or, very briefly:

```
[1,7,9,21,32,77].map(function(n,i){ return n * [2,3][i%2]; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to return a modified array that if the elements of the initial one is:

- in even position, then multiply the element by 2.
- in odd position, then multiply the element by 3.

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to get this one-liner

```js
console.log([1,7,9,21,32,77].map((num,ind) => num * (ind % 2 === 0 ? 2 : 3)));
```

This will output the desired

```
[2, 21, 18, 63, 64, 231]
```